# Admin entries 404'ing

Tags: entries, error, 404

I've transferred a Craft site (I didn't build it) from staging to production. All the existing content is showing up on the front end but when I try to edit entries that aren't static pages, the edit pages are 404'ing.

[image: 404]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

-- Update

Here's the contents of the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

general.php

```
<?php

/**
 * General Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's general configuration settings go in here.
 * You can see a list of the default settings craft/app/etc/config/defaults/general.php
*/

return array(

);
```

Comment: Is it just the entries that are 404'ing or every page of the CP?

Comment: Just the entries.

Comment: Some .htaccess rule interfering with the request?

Comment: Just posted .htaccess contents. Doesn't look like anything out of the ordinary but then again I'm not overly familiar with Craft.

Comment: Can you share what's in your craft/config/general.php file?

Comment: It appears to be empty.

Comment: Maybe someone else has some ideas... I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: It appears that even when they click New Entry to create content, it takes them to a 404 page. Does that trigger any further thoughts?

Comment: Not particularly... if you can't get it supported send some CP/FTP creds over to support@buildwithcraft.com and we'll take a stab at it.

Comment: Was anyone able to determine what the issue with this was?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to trace my particular issue to an old PCRE version which resulted in long regular expression strings to silently fail... causing the 'preg_match' to not match the edit entries string found here:

```
craft/app/etc/web/UrlManager.php:387
```

A quick test:

```
<?php
$path = 'entries/homepage/1-homepage';
$regexPattern = 'entries\/(?P<sectionHandle>(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\/(?P<entryId>\d+)(?:-(?:[\p{L}\p{N}\._\-]+))?';

var_dump(preg_match('/^'.$regexPattern.'$/u', $path, $match));
```

Should output in: 1 but was resulting in 0

The server is running a very old (from 2006) version of PCRE (PHP 5.3.3).

Running the following command:

```
pcretest -C
```

Resulted in the following version:

```
PCRE version 6.6 06-Feb-2006
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  No Unicode properties support
  Newline character is LF
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

This issue does not persist with the following version of PCRE (from a local Vagrant box):

```
PCRE version 7.8 2008-09-05
Compiled with
  UTF-8 support
  Unicode properties support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

I ended up solving this issue by migrating the sever to an AWS instance running PHP v5.6  You could also upgrade/rebuild PHP, but there are too many dependencies on the server.  I also tried increasing the backtrace and recursion limits, without success:

I tried adding this to my .htaccess file (FYI: I do not recommend setting this to 2Mb):

```
php_value pcre.backtrack_limit 2097152
php_value pcre.recursion_limit 2097152
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow... nice catch and thanks for sharing.