# Successful login with 'requireLogin' redirects to 404.shtml

Tags: login, 404

I have recently migrated an intranet to its production environment, and the requireLogin is misbehaving:

1. I'd go to intranet.example.com/
2. Log in with my details
3. Craft will redirect me to **intranet.example.com/404.shtml**, showing 'Layout file - This content should not be seen.'

   - this page doesn't exist, and I can't find any reference to 404.shtml on any page.
4. If I reload intranet.example.com/, it will show me the homepage, logged in. It works fine after that
5. I can log out and in again, it will work fine. I need to log out, close the browser and log in again to replicate the error

I have no redirects or have changed anything on the Craft config. Basically is a default 2.5 installation with new templates.

It works fine both locally (MAMP) and on my dev environment, but not on the server I just migrated it to.

Comment: After reading [this issue with old PHP](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/admin-entries-404ing?rq=1) I checked my server, and is running PHP 5.5, with 128M of memory and safe mode disabled.

Comment: 404.shtml isn't a Craft file... I'm guessing your host/web server is redirect to it (for whatever reason)?

Comment: @BradBell ok I was guessing that too, because I couldn't find that file! I'll ask them about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the http headers, and apparently my server was redirecting to a 404 page because the favicon.ico was missing.

As soon as I uploaded one it all worked fine again.